# SQL statement perform minus operation on column

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

I was having some difficulty when trying to perform a minus operation for the column using SQL statement. So here is the code for the servlet:

```
else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("UpdateSlot")) {
        String gameID = request.getParameter("gameID");

        String sqlStr = "UPDATE ... WHERE gameID = '" + gameID + "'";
        try {

            int rSet = db.executeUpdate(sqlStr);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My game table as such:

[image]

So basically when each time the SQL is executed, I want the gameCapacity to minus by 1. But I not sure how to convert the varChar into integer and perform a minus operation by using SQL statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: mysql will silently treat it like a number if you use it in a numeric context  -ie `gamecapacity = gamecapacity - 1` will just work

Comment: why do you have numbers in varchar type column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special - MySQL will recognise that you are using `gameCapacity` in a numeric context, and thus will allow you to perform arithmetic operations on it.

```
update ... set gameCapacity = gameCapacity -1 where ...
```

Should be all that you need.

if you can, it would also be worth converting that field to an integer.

Comment: What if I wanted to minus some number variable instead of 1?